# Linq to entities to return a list that contains elements from another list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have tried repeated different things to do this.
I need to query a database and return only the records that have a date that is contained in a List - like a dynamic "Where" statement.
I am sure it will involve => but cannot get the syntax correct.

I am building a short list below to test, but it could have any amount of items.

Below needs to return just the records where total.date_reference is contained in datesToShow.

```
          List<DateTime> datesToShow = new List<DateTime>();
        datesToShow.Add(new DateTime(2016, 9, 22));
        datesToShow.Add(new DateTime(2016, 9, 21));

        var todays_totals = (from total in dbContext.daily_totals
                              select new
                             {
                                 total.customer.customer_name,
                                 total.date_reference,
                                 total.EDI_PODs_sent,
                                 total.open_stops,
                                 total.total_pieces,
                                 total.new_stops,
                                 total.total_weight,
                                 total.Unsent_PODs_released,
                                 total.Unsent_PODs_unreleased,
                                 total.last_updated
                             }).ToArray();
```

If I do this:

```
    var todays_totals = (from total in dbContext.daily_totals
                             select new
                          {
                              total.customer.customer_name,
                              total.date_reference,
                              total.EDI_PODs_sent,
                              total.open_stops,
                              total.total_pieces,
                              total.new_stops,
                              total.total_weight,
                              total.Unsent_PODs_released,
                              total.Unsent_PODs_unreleased,
                              total.last_updated
                          }).Where(el => datesToShow.Contains(el.date_reference)).ToArray();
```

I get a " Unknown method Where(?)..."
I have tried using both a list and a array like:

```
   DateTime[] datesToShow = new DateTime[] 
        {
            new DateTime (2016,9,22),
            new DateTime (2016,9,23)
        };
```

I would also be fine with a new result set that is a subset of todays_totals.
something like the below (where I actually started from)

```
 var newList = (from t in todays_totals where (t=>datesToShow.Contains(t.date_reference))).ToArray();
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using lambda expressions?

Comment: Not at all BviLLeKid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `Contains` extension method:

```
     var todays_totals = (from total in dbContext.daily_totals
                          where datesToShow.Contains(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(total.date_reference))
                          select new
                         {
                             total.customer.customer_name,
                             total.date_reference,
                             total.EDI_PODs_sent,
                             total.open_stops,
                             total.total_pieces,
                             total.new_stops,
                             total.total_weight,
                             total.Unsent_PODs_released,
                             total.Unsent_PODs_unreleased,
                             total.last_updated
                         }).ToArray();
```

[`DbFunction.TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx) will help you to clean your dates in case they come with time.

Comment: No matter how I try and enter this one I get a error, if I keep the DbFunctions there then I get a Unknown Medthod Where(?) and even if I remove the TruncateTime part I get the same thing.

Comment: there is a second error: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime' -- which seems to be pointing the way, but...?

Comment: oh, it's a compilation error, but `total.date_reference` is not a `DateTime` property?

Comment: that's the deal, is a nullable type, try converting your list to  `List<DateTime?> datesToShow = new List<DateTime?>();` or you can change your where condition to: `total.date_reference!=null && datesToShow.Contains(total.date_reference.Value)`

Comment: That did it, changing the list to nullable fixed the error.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There're two ways to do what you want, that are basicly the same:

1. Use LINQ `where` statement. They can take any valid C# expression that returns `bool`:

   ```
   (from total in dbContext.daily_totals
   where datesToShow.Contains(total.date_reference)
   select new
   {
       // your select items...
   }).ToArray();
   ```
2. Use LINQ extension method for `WHERE` clause, that will, as you pointed out, contain a lambda expression:

   ```
   (from total in dbContext.daily_totals
   select new
   {
       // your select items...
   })
   .Where(el => datesToShow.Contains(el.date_reference))
   .ToArray();
   ```

Comment: Anytime I use "where datesToShow.Contains(total.date_reference)"  I get a unknown member 'date_reference' error.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambda Expression:

```
List<DateTime> datesToShow = new List<DateTime>();

datesToShow.Add(new DateTime(2016, 9, 22));
datesToShow.Add(new DateTime(2016, 9, 21));

var todays_totals = dbContext.daily_totals.Where(o=> datesToShows.Contains(o.date_reference)).ToList();

//Result should be a list that contains records that match those 2 dates.
```

Hope this helps!